# Versioning of android APK

Tags: android, apk

Does it make any sense to **version Android APK in the version control system** (git, mercurial etc.)? Can anyone think of any strong (dis)advantage?

After trying it, I haven't spot much benefit of doing so. On the other hand, it wasn't harmful either. Since I wasn't able to find appropriate answer very quickly, thought that informed answer from an Android expert could be helpful reference.

Comment: You could build the version from the e.g. number of commits, hash rather than storing it manually. This will guarantee the version number is unique.

Comment: Ease of grabbing it if you need to run QA on old versions?  Of course a build system with archived artifacts is probably more appropriate for that.  The only disadvantage to it is increasing the amount of data stored in your system.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to versionate the APK, but use tags for storing the release of a versionCode in the PlayStore, so you can go back the code to that point.

There's no benefits in having older apks for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend create a 'development' branch and a 'release' branch that you will periodically merge with. You handle all of you changes and development work in the development branch and once you've gotten your app to a point you're ready to release it to the Play Store, increment "versionCode" and "versionName" and  merge the code into the release branch with a commit message indicating both the "versionCode" and "versionName". That way, if any build of your app ever experiences a problem you have the code at the correct snapshot the app was released so you can directly "pull" the code and implement a hotfix without having to stash or revert any (possibly destructive) changes you've made inside of your development branch. If you need to make a hotfix for code you've released, just create a temporary branch forking from the 'release' code that has the error. Make all your changes there, again increment "versionCode" and "versionName" and then merge the changes back into 'release' with a very meaningful commit message again indicating the increment "versionCode" and "versionName". This should be a simple Fast-Forward merge (best kind of merge). You'll wanna manually copy the changes over to the 'development' branch to avoid a non Fast-Forward merg when you eventually wanna push the code to release.

I'd also recommend adding a 'experimental' changes branch, that is forked from development so you can use that area as a sandbox for experimental changes that you don't want to disturb the work flow inside of the 'development' branch.

You only wanna "version Android APK" when pushing your code to the release branch in my code. This will help you fix a bug if an old release.